# Lista circular con orden alfabético

Tags: c

el siguiente código es una lista circular, inserta los elementos bien, sin embargo a la hora de eliminarlos tiene un error. Me gustaría saber donde esta el error :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode{

char data;
struct listNode *nextptr;
};

typedef struct listNode LISTNODE;
typedef LISTNODE *LISTNODEPTR;

void insert (LISTNODEPTR *, char);
char delete (LISTNODEPTR *, char);
int isEmpty (LISTNODEPTR);
void printList(LISTNODEPTR);
void instructions (void);


int main()

{

LISTNODEPTR startPtr=NULL;
int choice;
char item;

instructions();
printf("? ");
scanf("%d", &choice);

while(choice != 3 ){

    switch (choice){

        case 1:
            printf("Enter a character: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &item);
            insert(&startPtr, item);
            printList(startPtr);
           
            break;
        case 2:
        if (!isEmpty(startPtr)){
            printf("Enter character to be deleted: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &item);
            if(delete(&startPtr, item)){
                printf("%c deleted. \n", item);
                printf("\nola");
                printList(startPtr);
            }
            else
                printf("List is empty or the element doesn't exist \n\n");
            break;
        }

        default:
            printf("invalid choice \n\n");
            instructions();
            break;
    }
    printf("? ");
     scanf("%d", &choice);
  }
  printf("End of run\n");
  return 0;
  }

void instructions (void){
printf("Enter your choice: \n"
        "1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
        "2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
        "3 to end.\n");
 }

 void insert (LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value){

LISTNODEPTR newPtr, previousPtr, currentPtr, tempPtr;

newPtr = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));
if (newPtr != NULL){

    newPtr->data = value;
    newPtr->nextptr = NULL;
    previousPtr = NULL;
    currentPtr = *sPtr;
    tempPtr=*sPtr;
    while (currentPtr != NULL && value > (currentPtr->data)){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextptr;
        if (currentPtr==tempPtr){
            break;
        }
         }

    if(previousPtr == NULL){
        newPtr->nextptr = *sPtr;
        if (currentPtr==NULL){
            newPtr->nextptr=newPtr;
        }
        else{
            tempPtr->nextptr=newPtr;
        }
        *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        
    else{
        
        previousPtr->nextptr = newPtr;
        newPtr->nextptr = currentPtr;
        if (currentPtr==NULL){
            newPtr->nextptr=*sPtr;
        }
    }
}
else
    printf("%c not inserted. No memory available", value);
}
char delete(LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value){

LISTNODEPTR previousPtr, currentPtr, tempPtr;
printf("\n%p\n", tempPtr);
```

Presiento que el error esta en este if. Ya que al querer eliminar, si es la cabeza de la fila, a esta la llevará al final de la lista sin eliminarlo. Sin embargo al eliminar los siguientes a la cabeza, si lo hace.

```
 if(value == (*sPtr)->data){
     tempPtr = *sPtr;
     *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextptr;
     free(tempPtr);
     printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
     return value;
          }
 else{
     previousPtr = *sPtr;
     currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextptr;
     printf("\n%p", tempPtr);

     while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value){
         previousPtr = currentPtr;
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextptr;
         printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
     }
     if(currentPtr != NULL){
        tempPtr = currentPtr;
         previousPtr->nextptr = currentPtr-> nextptr;
         free(tempPtr);
         printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
         return value;
     }
     printf("\n%p\n", tempPtr);
 }
 return '\0';



}


int isEmpty(LISTNODEPTR sPtr)
{
return sPtr == NULL;
}

void printList(LISTNODEPTR currentPtr){
LISTNODEPTR tempPtr;
tempPtr=currentPtr;
if (currentPtr == NULL)
printf("list is empty \n\n");
while(1){
    printf("(%p) %c -->(%p) ",currentPtr, currentPtr->data, currentPtr->nextptr );
    currentPtr = currentPtr->nextptr;
    if (currentPtr==tempPtr||currentPtr==NULL){
        break;
    }
   }
  }
```

A la hora de eliminar, por ejemplo se introduzca a, b y c, y yo quiero eliminar a, el código lo cambia a b, c y a. No tengo idea de el por qué. Gracias :)

Comment: Por favor, las etiquetas son **muy importantes**. No has recibido ninguna respuesta ni ningún *feeback* porqué **no has indicado el lenguaje que estás usando**. Muchos usuarios monitorizan las etiquetas de su interés. Tenlo en cuenta para futuras consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Si es una lista circular, y tienes `a->b->c->a` y quieres eliminar el nodo `a`, tienes que ir al nodo `c` y hacer que apunte a `b`, después ya puedes eliminar el nodo `a`.

Es decir, tienes que dar el mismo tratamiento a todos los nodos, sin importar su posición. El `if` de la función `delete` sobra.

```
char delete(LISTNODEPTR *sPtr, char value)
{
    LISTNODEPTR previousPtr, currentPtr, tempPtr;
    printf("\n%p\n", tempPtr);

    // if(value == (*sPtr)->data){
    //     tempPtr = *sPtr;
    //     *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextptr;
    //     free(tempPtr);
    //     printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
    //     return value;
    // } else {
        previousPtr = *sPtr;
        currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextptr;
        printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
    
        while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value){
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextptr;
            printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
        }

        if(currentPtr != NULL){
            tempPtr = currentPtr;
            previousPtr->nextptr = currentPtr-> nextptr;
            free(tempPtr);
            printf("\n%p", tempPtr);
            return value;
        }
        printf("\n%p\n", tempPtr);
    // }
    return '\0';
}
```